# Android-how to set image in particular layout starting center point?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-cardview

I want to set like below image :

[image]

pls help me to solve out this layout..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your Layout code.

Comment: What have you tries. post your xml code

Comment: You want to align half of image over Recycler view?

Comment: this is only photo design i have no any code for it but i want to do it.. @AndroidHacker

Answer (score 0):

**BASIC**

> CardView have higher elevation than ImageView. So just set higher
>   elevation for ImageView.

Here we go ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.Splash"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_splash"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is just for test"
                />

            </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cross"
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the screen shot ....

[image]

Comment: good try but remove elevation from last image than this not work - @AndroidHacker